# 6-pin EPS - is it real? And can I use 8-pin instead?

Tags: motherboard, power-supply, pin

There's this 2-socket server motherboard [ASUS WS C621E SAGE](https://dlcdnets.asus.com/pub/ASUS/mb/Socket3647/WS_C621E_SAGE/Manual/E15371_WS_C621E_SAGE_UM_V6_WEB.pdf).

It has two 8-pin connectors and one 6-pin connector. I assume that two 8-pin connectors are for powering two CPUs, but on page 2-6 of the manual they only plug one 8-pin alone or 8-pin and 6-pin plugs together. On page 1-28 they imply that 6-pin connector is for additional powering of videocards.

I am confused. How many plugs on my PSU do you think I would need to plan for for this card to run on max settings -- with both CPUs and many GPUs?

And second, and most important, what is 6-pin EPS connector? If you look on page 1-28 6-pin connector is clearly not 6-pin PCI and it looks like 8-pin EPS with two side pins removed. But googling for 6-pin EPS doesn't produce any meaningful results. What is 6-pin EPS?

Will I be able to force 8-pin EPS into it? Or cut two superfluous pins? Would it not fry the mobo?

--

On further inspection, if you look on page 1-28 of the manual you can see how +12V goes to upper pins on 8-pin connector and to lower pins on 6-pin connector, which is in agreement with 6-pin PCIe specifications, according to this diagram:

[image]

Given that the upper-central hole on the 6-pin mobo connector is square and the peg on the 6-pin PCIe plug is round, I will be able to connect the two. But should I? Wouldn't want to fry this expensive mobo...

Comment: What PSU were you going to use with this motherboard?

Comment: It was I believe Intel's server PSU with custom soldering. But I got a response from ASUS customer service and they say one can use standard 6-pin PCI plug on this 6-pin connector.

Answer (score 1):

It appears you need 1 8 pin connector for EACH cpu you install. And you need the 6 pin connector if you want more than 2 expansion cards. There are 2 types of 6 pin connectors I could find online, one for GPU and one for motherboards.

related link: https://forums.evga.com/6-pin-power-connector-on-motherboard-m2015223.aspx